# Changing an element in a different Frame in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, frame, wxwidgets

I have a small program that batch handles files. These files use a map file to load certain settings. The map file has a line at the top that specifies for what directory it is for.

Currently I am able to read the line and assign it to the source path variable (sPath). I want to update the TextCtrl for the Source Directory, however it is in the MainFrame class and I load the map file in a different class.

```
class Process(wx.Panel):

    def loadMap(self, event):
    MainFrame.sPath = str(mapFile.readline()).strip("\n")
    MainFrame.loadSource(MainFrame())

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="DICOM Toolkit", size=(800,705))
        self.srcTc = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, 131, '', size=(600,25), style=wx.TE_READONLY)

    def loadSource(self):
        self.srcTc.SetValue(MainFrame.sPath)
```

I eliminated most of the code and what's above is where it is giving me trouble. How do I change self.srcTc in the MainFrame class from either the Process class or a function in the MainFrame class? I am having trouble actually pointing to self.srcTc without a handler that stems from the MainFrame class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want has to look like something like that (without a working example):

```
class Process(wx.Panel):
    def loadMap(self, event):
        frame = MainFrame()
        frame.sPath = str(mapFile.readline()).strip("\n")
        frame.loadSource()
```

when using `MainFrame.sPath = ...` you're not actually changing sPath to a MainFrame you created, but to the class itself, then you create it, in `MainFrame()` without storing a reference to it (assign it to a variable for example). So, you can't access it from somewhere other than "inside" the class itself as `self`.

The solution is to create an instance of a `MainFrame` and operate on it. Once you create it and assign it to a variable, you can manipulate the `.sPath` attribute and call `loadSource()`.

**UPDATE**: From you code snippet, it seems you create the `MainFrame` instance in the end of the file: `MainFrame().Show()`, and then in the `loadMap` method, you create a new one.

What you should do is this, in the end of your file:

```
app = wx.App(0)
#MainFrame().Show()
mainFrame = MainFrame() # or, insteadof making it a global variable, pass it as an argument to the objects you create, or store a reference to it anywhere else.
mainFrame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

and in the `loadMap` method:

```
def loadMap(self, event):
    global mainFrame # or wherever you stored the reference to it
    # ...
    # remove this:
    # mainFrame = MainFrame()
    # set the sPath to the OBJECT mainFrame not the CLASS MainFrame
    mainFrame.sPath = str(mapFile.readline()).strip("\n")
    mainFrame.srcTc.SetValue(MainFrame.sPath)
```

Now this way, it should work.
The problem was that you are creating another frame, changing its path and updating its text, but you are not showing it. The correction is to store the actual window that is being shown, and update this one.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear examples, but your suggestion has worked so to some extent. I can now SetValue and GetValue on the TextCtrl in the MainFrame class from the Process class. However it doesn't update on screen.

Comment: @wtfomgjohnny Your problem seems to be with OOP in Python in general not with wxPython and GUI (from what I can see here). Just a guess here: are you calling the `wx.App` instance's `.MainLoop()` method? Without a working example I cannot see the problem...

Comment: Here is the complete code with my implementation of your suggestion.
http://pastebin.com/aWr0fse0

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish this sort of thing. You can pass a handle to your panel class that can call whatever it needs in the parent to set the value (i.e. parent.myTxtCtrl.SetValue(val) ) or you can use pubsub. I personally recommend the latter as it's much more flexible and less prone to breakage as you change your program. I wrote the following tutorial that should get you up to speed: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you Mike, I've actually read many of your tutorials and articles, they are indeed helpful.

Right now I'm using jadkik94's method and it works except the actual TextCtrl doesn't display the text. It gets assigned a value and I can call GetValue() and have it return the correct information but it's not writing it in the actual box.